# Run command in existing Docker using Jenkins-Pipelines

Tags: docker, jenkins

I'm new with Jenkins-Groovy and try to run a command within an existing Docker-Container and before setting some environmental-variables using a Jenkins-Pipeline.

The bash-script used for right now (so just executing it from the command line) looks like that and works:

```
export LIB_ROOT=/usr/local/LIBS
export TMP_MAC_ADDRESS=b5:17:a3:28:55:ea

sudo docker run --rm -i -v "$LIB_ROOT":/usr/local/LIBS/from-host -v /home/sbuild/Dockerfiles/Sfiles/mnt:/home/sbuild/mount --mac-address="$TMP_MAC_ADDRESS" -t sbuild:current
```

Afterwards I want to build some of my sources (mounted) inside the Docker-Container using something like:

```
python3 batchCompile.sh ../mount/src.zip
```

Right now I've been trying to write it like that in my Jenkins:

```
            node ('linux-slave') {
                withEnv(['PATH=/usr/local/LIBS:/usr/local/MATLAB/from-host  -v /home/sbuild/Dockerfiles/Sfiles/mnt:/home/sbuild/mount --mac-address=b5:17:a3:28:55:ea']) {
                    docker.image('sbuild').inside {
                    sh 'echo $PATH'
                    sh 'mvn --version'
                    }
                }
                sh 'echo $PATH'
            }
```

Yet this just fails with an opaque message:

```
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 71: Expected a symbol @ line 71, column 25.
                           docker.image('sbuild:current').inside {
                           ^

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
```

I'm not able to figure out what is running wrong.
So I was just trying to get inside the Docker and look what I can do from there. With this little script I was experimenting a little:

```
script{
    docker.image('sbuild:current').inside{
    sh 'touch asdf'
    sh 'cd /home/sbuild/'
    sh 'pwd'
}
```

Yet by default I'm just working from the Jeninks-Folder and none of these commands are actually called inside the Docker. Also the container doesn't seem to run at any time.

How do I have to write my code to start the Docker I had configured and use commands inside?

There's some documentation outside for creating new Docker containers, but I have difficulties to figure out how to make sense of that error message and how to properly debug.

Edit 1: The Dockerfile:

```
FROM labs:R2018

# Avoid interaction
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

# Set user to root
USER root

# =========== Basic Configuration ======================================================
# Update the system
#RUN apt-get -y update \
#    && apt-get install -y sudo build-essential git python python-dev \
#    python-setuptools make g++ cmake gfortran ipython swig ant python-numpy \
#    python-scipy python-matplotlib cython python-lxml python-nose python-jpype \
#    libboost-dev jcc git subversion wget zlib1g-dev pkg-config clang

# Install system libs
# RUN apt-get install sudo

# ========== Install pip for managing python packages ==================================
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip python-lxml && pip install cython
# Install simulix dependencies

RUN apt-get install -y git

RUN apt-get install --assume-yes python
RUN apt-get install --assume-yes cmake
RUN apt-get install --assume-yes mingw-w64
# Add User
#RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' docker
#RUN adduser docker sudo
#RUN echo '%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers

USER build

# Install simulix
WORKDIR /home/sbuild
RUN git clone https://github.com/***.git
RUN mkdir mount

WORKDIR /home/sbuild/Sfiles
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: Can you add the Dockerfile for `sbuild:current`?

Comment: @MTCoster - added

Answer (score 1):

When I use Docker with Jenkins Pipeline I do it with the `sh` step only:

```
try {
    stage('Start Docker') {
        sh 'docker-compose up'
    }

    stage('Build project') {
        sh 'docker-compose exec my_service make:build
    }
} catch (Error e)
    // Maybe do something
} finally {
    sh 'docker-compose stop'
}
```

You want to surround your stages with a try/catch/finally block to always stop the docker containers in case of failure.

Comment: As said I'm really new to Jenkins-Groovy/Docker. Would you mind to edit the script in a way I'm able to use it?

Comment: Well, you didn't paste your pipeline. And what I gave you is a sort of skeleton to do whatever you want. Maybe you should RTFM a little bit more if you don't see how to integrate your logic with this skeleton.